# Error after upload codeigniter website from one hosting to another visit fink.pk its not coming proper website layout

Tags: database

please visit my website fink.pk I m uploaded this website from one hosting to another it's not opening proper

Answer (score 0):

That's because some resources are missing like the directories templatejs and templatecss (and all their files). In your browser open the console and go to the section "Network" to know what files are missing